# Is there a complex version of PeriodogramArray?

Tags: sound, signal-processing

I am trying to build some functions to help me work with audio data collected as time streams but converted to the frequency domain. The frequency domain results must be complex because phase is important in my application. `PeriodogramArray` does everything I need, such as tidy application of windowing functions and averaging over several partitions.
The problem is that it only returns power spectra, which are magnitude only.

I can build these functions from scratch using `Fourier`, but I would far prefer to use built-in functions operating directly on `Audio` objects. Is there any way to coerce `PeriodogramArray` to return complex results, or is there a different (convenient) function I am unaware of?

Comment: It appears that I did not investigate SpectrogramArray enough before posting this. SpectrogramArray returns complex values. I will go down this rabbit hole and post something if it works out.

Comment: Maybe you need is `SpectrogramArray`